# Reading a matrix from cin

Tags: c++

hi I'm trying to read that input

```
2
2
9 97
8 56
3
1 18 6
16 42 100
25 16 17
```

I can't get the numbers 9, 97, 8, 56 and store them in a vector of

here is my attempt

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int test;

    cin >> test;

    while (test--)
    {
        int ss_i;
        cin >> ss_i;

        vector<int> A(ss_i*ss_i);



    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why negating my question ?!

Comment: That's completely nonsensical code. You're just creating a new vector instance in each iteration: `vector<int> A(ss_i*ss_i);` (which can be considered a NOP).

Comment: Why I downvoted your question? Your research efforts seem to be extremely low: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B+read+a+matrix+from+cin The DV button tooltip already tells this to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fill a `string` and then access the integers through a [`std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/http://).
also consider [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) to store those integers into a `vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(){

    int size{ 16 };

    std::vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(size); //reserve memory


    for (int i = 0; i < size;){
        std::string ss_i; //number(s) to push_back


        std::cout << "Type in " << size - i << " more integers: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, ss_i);

        std::istringstream stringstream(ss_i); //load into stream

        int n;
        while (stringstream >> n){
            i++;
            numbers.push_back(n); //add to the vector
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The vector contains:\n";
    for (auto i : numbers){
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example Run:

```
Type in 16 more integers: 2
Type in 15 more integers: 2
Type in 14 more integers: 9 97
Type in 12 more integers: 8 56
Type in 10 more integers: 3
Type in 9 more integers: 1
Type in 8 more integers: 18 6
Type in 6 more integers: 16 42
Type in 4 more integers: 100 25 16 17
The vector contains:
2 2 9 97 8 56 3 1 18 6 16 42 100 25 16 17
```

Comment: the numbers not in a column, the numbers is separated  by a space.

Comment: this is going to be way more difficult. You'll have to work with `strings` to get that done.

Comment: but am sorry that's not the solution to my problem

Comment: @StackDanny That's not rocket science, well. Just use `std::getline()` and `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @Andre 1st of all you should understand the structure of your input file. It tells you to read 2 matrcies, 1st one with 2x2 dimension, second one with 3x3 dimension. Set up the appropriate data structures as necessary and parse the file, done.

Comment: @Andre I edited it. Does it please you now?

Comment: [don't use `endl` unless really necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714), `cout << '\n'` is enough